# Select statement returns the incorrect results

Tags: sql, select

I have been trying to figure out the correct SQL for **question number 13** in [this](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations) tutorial. None of the other questions concern me, just #13.

Essentially, what the question asks is to find out all the movies that 'Julie Andrews' played in, and from that result, select the actors who played the leading actors in those movies. Sounds simple enough, but everything I try is failing. The following:

```
select title, name from movie
  join casting on movie.id=movieid
  join actor on actorid=actor.id
  where (name = 'Julie Andrews' ) 
  and ord=1
```

selects the movies that she was in and she was the lead actor. What I need is the lead actors for movies she was in, not the movies she played the lead in.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a start: Why are you SELECTing title, name from movie if you're looking for actors?

Comment: Another hint - you're going to need another reference to `actor`, to get the names.  What do you need to join it too?  What's supposed to happen if two movies share the same lead actor/actress (other than Julie Andrews)?

Comment: Are you familiar with aliases yet? You can have two joins to the same table and give them different aliases - e.g. `join casting as cast_julie on movie.id = cast_julie.movieid` and later `join casting as cast_mainactor on movie.id = cast_mainactor.movieid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select movie.title, actor.name
from movie, actor, casting, (SELECT movieid from casting join actor 
on actor.id=casting.actorid where actor.name = 'Julie Andrews') JAM
where movie.id = JAM.movieid and actor.id = casting.actorid
and casting.movieid=JAM.movieid and casting.ord=1
group by movie.title
```

Comment: How about adding `GROUP BY movie.title` and then remove `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @KevinSjöberg Yes, that did the trick. I've edited my response. But I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to eliminate the duplicate entry just at the joins...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select m.title, a.name
from movie m
join casting c on m.id = c.movieid
   and ord = 1
join actor a on a.id = c.actorid
where exists (select *
   from casting c2
   join actor a2 on c2.actorid = a2.id
      and a2.name = 'Julie Andrews'
   where c2.movieid = m.id
)
```